# Grabbing info from two different tables, assistance

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a members page. For the rank it shows numbers so I made another table that has the rank id (1,2,3 etc) and added a name to it also.
Here is my code.

```
<?php 
$getCoB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` 
                       WHERE `CoB` = '1' && `user_state` = '1' ORDER BY `id`");
$id = ($getCoB['rank']);
$rankInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ranks` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");?>

<h2 class="title">Council of Balance members</h2>
<style>tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color:#F0F0F0;}</style>
<div style='padding:5px;'>
<?php               
if(mysql_num_rows($getCoB) == 0)
{
    echo "There are no Council of Balance members.";
} else {
    echo "<table cellpadding=20 width=100%>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCoB))
    {
        echo "<tr><td style='background-color:transparent;'><b>". $row['name'] 
         . "</b></td><td>Rank: ".$rankInfo['name']." <br/> Role: ". $row['role']."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

The problem is `rankInfo['name']` is not showing up. I tried to do something on this line `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCoB))` and tried to make it something like this `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCoB)) || while($rank = mysql_fetch_assoc($rankInfo)` and changed this part `<td>Rank: ". $rankInfo['name'] . "` to this `<td>Rank: ". $rank['name'] . "` but I end up with an error. If I leave it like it is, it just shows **Rank:** without the name I added into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your two queries into one using an inner join.

```
<?php
$getCoB = mysql_query("SELECT m.name as member_name, m.role, r.name as rank_name 
                       FROM `members` as m INNER JOIN `ranks` as r ON m.rank = r.id 
                       WHERE `CoB` = '1' && `user_state` = '1' ORDER BY m.id");
?>
```

Because of how INNER JOIN works, this will only display members who have corresponding records in the ranks table. If there are some members that you want to display that have no rank record, use LEFT JOIN instead.

Then when you echo out the data, be sure to refer to the item you have fetched (`$row`) each time. In your code, you are referring to `$rankInfo['name']`, where `$rankInfo` is not a variable, but a mysql query from which no rows have been fetched.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCoB)) {
    echo "<tr><td style='background-color:transparent;'><b>". $row['member_name']
    . "</b></td><td>Rank: ". $row['rank_name'] . " <br/> Role: " . $row['role'] . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: You are my hero, I would have never knew of this. Thank you so much for this. If you have any sites that could help better myself into things like this please share if you want, because I love using _Php_ but somethings are way over my head.

Comment: @GrimmRP You're welcome. I really don't have a specific tutorial site to recommend for PHP. Everyone learns differently. For me the best way is to just do what I'm trying to learn _a lot_. If you're not sure how something works, check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/), and if you have questions, then come here. Try to find questions similar to yours before you ask a new one. Most problems people run across when they're starting out already have good Q & A's. And if what you read doesn't exactly address your problem, you'll probably learn something else useful anyway.